# I recieve this error: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' but it still works

Tags: python, valueerror

Its saying that error at `variable=int(file.readline())`  but it seems it still works . I couldn't understand the error and I am wondering if I should fix it. By the way the file consists of integers completely.

Comment: You likely have an empty line at the end of your file. You'd need to wrap this code in a `try`, or check to make sure the line is parsable before calling `int`.

Comment: @C.Nivs `int()` doesn't care about extra whitespace.  `int("   5   ")` works just fine.

Comment: @C.Nivs Something like `int("  \t23 \r\n")` is perfectly valid.

Comment: it does care about only whitespace though, `int(' ')` and `int('3.14')` or anything that's a floating point will give this error. Make sure it's neither of those two. `int(float('3.14'))` works for example.